# startActivity doesn't work on some real devices (s3, s4, Fly IQ451)

Tags: android, android-intent, device, start-activity

I have very weird problem. This simple code:

```
 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Hello worlds" + date_month_year, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    parsedDate = dateFormatter.parse(date_month_year);
    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), CalendarHoursViewActivity.class);
    i.putExtra("choosed_date", date_month_year);
    startActivity(i);
```

do not work on such devices as: Samsung S3, Samsung S4, Fly IQ451.
But it works successfully on Nexus 4, Samsung galaxy note. 
AndroidManifest looks like good:

```
android:minSdkVersion="13"
android:targetSdkVersion="16"
```

and my Activity I want to start is also in manifest.

Besides, Toast is showing on all devices, unlike Activity starting.

What can be reason and solution of such weird issue?

Comment: use Activity context `Intent i = new Intent(ActivityName.this, CalendarHoursViewActivity.class)` and try

Comment: tried this , but the same result

Comment: i have a samsung galaxy s3 and it works fine. show us your manifest

Comment: the problem is probably your context, using `getApplicationContext` is usually not a good idea

Comment: @RikkiTikkiTavi are you calling `startActivtiy` in a non activity class?

Comment: no, in Activity class

Comment: @RikkiTikkiTavi i don't see any reason why it won't work. does your app crash. have you declared the activity in manifest?

Comment: yes. app is not crashes. There is only one Toast at s4 and no Activity shows.

Comment: i guess s4 has api version as 17, i know this may not be your answer but give it a try!!!!:)

Comment: So what does the log say about it when you launch it? There should be a message for even an attempted/failed intent.

Comment: Post your logcat. Don't filter the logcat as you might miss something valuable/useful/important

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in getting ParsingException. There is English localisation on my device, so parcement date as 18-September-2013 was successful. And on listed devices there is another localisation and they got ParsingException in try block. So app wasn't shutting up but startActivity wasn't call. So the issue solved.